# How to call javascript for custom Web Edit Button of RTE in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, richtext-editor

I need to add custom button of template     /sitecore/templates/System/WebEdit/WebEdit Button to RTE in Experience Editor. And invoke my custom js function on click. How I can implement that?

I've added my function in js-file and included file in

```
<clientscripts><everypage> </everypage></clientscripts>
```

I've tried invoke my function from Command using

```
 Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Eval("myFunction()")
```

and I've tried to add

```
javascript:myFunction()
```

in Click field of sitecore item.
But my function is always undefined.

How can I add javascript with my function to EE and call it for my custom button?

Comment: Does your "myFunction()" call  is available from browser console?

Comment: @Anton no, I see undefined. Is there a specific way to add js script in EE mode?

Comment: a lot of ways to do it, check this article https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/injecting-resources-into-experience-editor/ 
One of possible ways:
@if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor)
{
    <script src="pathtojs"></script>
}

Comment: @Anton thanks, I'll try to add pipeline. My project is sitecore module, not a site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any other working way to do that, only this patch works for me

```
<pipelines>
  <group groupName="ExperienceEditor" name="ExperienceEditor">
    <pipelines>
      <pageEditingScripts>
        <processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.PageEditingScripts.AddDeclaredScripts, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor">
          <path patch:after="*[last()]">/sitecore modules/Shell/MyApp/js/myCustom.js</path>
        </processor>
      </pageEditingScripts>
    </pipelines>
  </group>
</pipelines>
```

So, I added my custom js to list of paths and as I got, it will be bundled with others scripts for EE.